# Is there a way to put the cursor where the mouse is clicked in multiline TextFields?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am using a multiline textfield similar to the Life Story field in the Flutter gallery [textformfield example](https://flutter.github.io/samples/gallery/#/material/text-form-field).

I can't get the cursor to stay where I put it using the mouse. You can use the arrow keys to move it where you want it.

I'm expecting to be able to place my cursor anywhere I'd like in the text by clicking in with my mouse/pointer.

What is actually happening is this. If there is more than one line of text, when the user tries to put the cursor in a line other than the first the cursor jumps to the first line. It seems to jump to the horizontal position in the first line that is closest to the horizontal position the user clicked in the succeeding lines.

- To reproduce enter a long string of text or type a shorter line of text, hit return, and enter another line of text.
- Try to click into the second line. (If the second line of text is longer than the first you'll see some interesting behavior when you click in a position beyond the length of the first line.)

main.dart:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) =>Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: Center(
        child:TextFormField(
          maxLines: null,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

pubspec.yaml:

```
name: textformfield_demo
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Flutter (Channel dev, v1.10.16, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G103, locale en-US)

Dart VM version: 2.5.1

Thanks for your help!